# Understanding LORA XL1276-P01 Module

Tags: lora

i'm trying to understand Lora Modem base on XL1276-P01 module. and this is the circuit I got from doing tracing on the module. what is the function of the block I circled?
I would love to understand this, but i dont know yet what's the keyword to explore it.
[image]
Note : the "?" sign means just a solder pad without component attached

Thanks.

Comment: They are all filters and impedance matching networks.

Comment: I'm a rookie at RF so I dare not post an answer. This appears to be a semiduplex transceiver. Orange is the tx path and blue is the rx path - the RF switch toggles between them, only one is active at the same time.

What exactly all of these passives do is a bit hard to say without reading up on the RFIC part in detail. The various parts are either PA matching/impedance matching,  phase adjustment or filtering. Capacitors in series are DC blocking. The parts to the far right in the green circle is a pi filter which also forms a lowpass filter together with the parts on the tx path.